# Как правильно работать со строками неопределенной длины на С?

Tags: c, строки, файлы, память

Как правильнее работать со строками, длина которых заранее неизвестна?

Т.е. допустим есть функция, которая возврвращает какое-то сообщение. Сообщение может быть очен длинным.

```
char* get_hello() {
    char buffer[1024000];
    memset(buffer, 0, 1024000 * sizeof(char));
    ...
    while(fgets(...) != NULL) {
        sprintf(buffer, "%s%s", buffer, row);
    }
    ...
    char* result = malloc(sizeof(buffer) + 1);
    strncpy(buffer, result, sizeof(buffer));
    result[strlen(buffer)] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

Что здесь можно улучшить?

Comment: Можно перейти на С++

Comment: https://sucs.org/Knowledge/Help/Program%20Advisory/Reading%20an%20arbitrarily%20long%20line%20in%20C

Comment: @MaxZS, иногда С++ недоступен, например при написании кода для встроенных систем.

Comment: Помимо уже сказанного в ответах: `sizeof(char)` всегда = 1; обнулить буфер на стеке можно проще, используя `= {}`; копировать надо не весь `buffer`, а только то, что прочитано; вызывать `strlen(buffer)` не эффективно, если размер уже известен; ну и главный косяк - при использовании `buffer` в качестве источника и приемника одновременно в `sprintf` наступает UB.

Comment: Используйте GNU [getline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

У вас непонятно, хотите ли вы считывать весь файл или только строку - до первого `\n`. Если это файл, и весь - то лучше запросить его размер, выделить соответствующий буфер и считать все и сразу.

Если это файл непонятной длины (типа `stdin`) или вам надо остановиться по прочтении `\n` - то я бы выделил память (не в стеке, а сразу в куче - к чему эти лишние пересылки?) некоторой длины (грубо, каких нибудь 256 байт), и начал бы читать с помощью `fgets`. Ну, если буфера не хватает - увеличивал бы с помощью `realloc`, причем сразу в 2 раза, чтоб амортизированное количество переносов сделать `O(1)` и накапливал считанные куски строки в нем.

Примерно так.

Код нужен или реализуете сами? :)

**Update**: По просьбам трудящихся :) примерный набросок:

```
char* getString(FILE* f)
{
    int size   = 16, // размер буфера
        curpos = 0;  // текущая позиция
    char * buf = malloc(size);
    // if (buf == NULL) - все проверки допишите сами
    while(fgets(buf+curpos,size-curpos,f))
    {
        curpos += strlen(buf + curpos);
        if (*(buf+curpos-1) == '\n') return buf;
        if (size - curpos < 2)
        {
            buf = realloc(buf,size*=2);
        }
    }
    return buf;
};
```

Comment: код никогда не помешает :)

Comment: @YuriyOrlov Ну вот, смотрите...Примерно так, проверки я не делал, сами допишете, где надо. Главное - потом не забудьте `free` для возвращаемого значения сделать.

Comment: Вы забыли приведение `void*` в `char*` при `malloc` и `realloc`

Comment: Ну добавьте. Я его не компилировал, это так, как я написал - **_примерный набросок_**.

Comment: оно не мне надо, просто желательно давать как можно более полный ответ, если не лень

Comment: @YuriyOrlov в сях приведение выполняется неявно.

Answer (score 1):

```
FILE * pFile = ...
fseek( pFile, 0L, SEEK_SET );     // указатель текущей позиции файла в начале

fseek( pFile, 0L, SEEK_END );     // теперь - в самом конце

size_t fSize = ftell( pFile );   // `ftell` вернул Вам необходимый для размещения данных размер
```

Стоит только помнить о том, как работает ftell если Вы читаете бинарный поток.